# how to change routing of a existing symfony app/project to work on domain/server

Tags: php, symfony, deployment, routes

I'm new to deploying my own symfony project, but I can't figure out how to set the routing right.
Now my website opens index.html when going to www.domain.nl. I want that to refer to my home "/" in my symfony app.
I only uploaded the documents to the server. What do I need to change to make it work? Like changing data in the parameters.yml?
The documentation on the symfony site is a bit too vage for me. I also don't know how to call from the terminal to my website.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Symfony in the first place. You need to make changes in your htaccess file or your web server settings to make the Symfony home directory the web root.

Comment: Oke, thank you. And to which file do I need to refer?

Comment: What is your web server config? The answer depends on the web server you are using.